# How to make deferred promises in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 function $scope.one(); $scope.two(); $scope.three();

I want :

when one has finish, then two will execute,

when two has finish, then three will execute.

I was googling and this can be handled by deferred, but i dont know how to do this. i'm not found clear and simple explanation.

update:

```
$scope.login = function(){
        $http.post(URL+'auth/login', {email:'dummy@gmail.com', password:'password'}).then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    };

$scope.getData = function(){
        IngredientService.ingredients().then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    };
```

Comment: this is a good article for understanding promises in general : 
http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, for the execution order problem you can do the following - providing all functions return promises.

```
$scope.one()
  .then($scope.two)
  .then($scope.three);
```

**Tangent ahead.**

However this is probably indicative of a design flaw. Generally speaking you *probably* don't want to expose functions that return promises at the scope level - the scope is mainly for talking with the view, and the view cannot utilize promises. You *probably* want to move all of the logic in `$scope.one`, `$scope.two` and `$scope.three` to a service, and then invoke the chain above inside of a single function.

Now, if you want to expose an API to descendants of the scope, you should use a controller instead and communicate through directives. This is what is essentially going to be used in Angular 2.0 as well, with the removal of scopes and controllers entirely - all we will have will be directives that essentially have a controller and can require other directives.

```
const mod = angular.module('app', []);

class ParentCtrl {
  foo() {
    console.log('it works!');
  }
}

mod.directive('parent', function() {
  return { 
    controller: ParentCtrl
  };
});

mod.directive('child', function() {
  return {
    require: ['^parent'],
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
      $scope.parent = $ctrl;
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      // Unfortunately this is the only way to access required controllers from this controller at the moment. However, one could argue that shared logic should *really* go in services, and that the only thing required controllers should be used for is event binding (in the link function).
      $scope.parent.foo();
    }
  };
});
```

When you're exposing an API like this it makes sense to sometimes expose promises at this level. See my [codepen](http://codepen.io/aredherring/pen/NqMaYo?editors=101) for an example (check the console).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use async module. Especially the waterfall function which will fit to your requirements.

https://github.com/caolan/async

**[EDIT]**

You can do it like that with async :

```
$scope.login = function(callback) {
  if (success) {
    callback();
  } else {
    callback('my error');
  }
}

$scope.getData = function(callback) {
  callback(null, myData);
}

$scope.doIt = function(callback) {
  async.waterfall([$scope.login, $scope.getData], callback);
}
```

Comment: how to use it in angular?

Comment: Add it to your bower file (bower install --save async), add it in your vendors file (I don't know how you do it), and then async.waterfall([fn1, fn2, fn3], callback);

Comment: async.waterfall([$scope.login(), $scope.getData()]); i got errors.Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Comment: Do login login and getData methods have callback as first parameter ? And you should use login and getData without parentheses ? In other words, $scope.login = function(callback){} and async.waterfall([$scope.login, $scope.getData],callback);

Comment: i was update and give my code above, im not understood how to use this async

Comment: This will never work. `async` only works when functions are node-style callbacks. Do not use `async` in Angular unless the functions you are invoking use callbacks (and no functions that are in standard Angular do; they all return promises).